# JavaScript video libraries overwriting each other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using two different libraries for embedding YouTube-Videos. One alone works fine but if i include them both, the second one (depending on the javascript include order) doesn't work. There are no errors in the console but i narrowed it down to the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function, which is called by the YouTube-API the both libs use.

The first library (**[jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer)**) calls this (around line 26):

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    console.log('ytplayer onYouTubeIframeAPIReady');

    if (ytp.YTAPIReady) return;
    ytp.YTAPIReady = true;
    jQuery(document).trigger("YTAPIReady");
}
```

The second library (**[jarallax](https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax)**) does this (around line 665):

```
// Creates deferred so, other players know when to wait.
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {

    console.log("jarallax onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = null;
    loadingYoutubeDeffer.resolve('done');
    callback();
};
```

I added the `console.log()`'s, only one or the other is logged.

What can i do, so that both functions are called and both libraries are correctly initialized?

Comment: Why am i getting downvotes for this?

Comment: @mplungjan It's original code from the library, even if i uncomment it, the other one is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the global function `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` was overwritten by **jarallax**, i stored any previous reference to the function and called it:

```
// Creates deferred so, other players know when to wait.
var f = window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    f();
    console.log("jarallax onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = null;
    loadingYoutubeDeffer.resolve('done');
    callback();
};
```